# Multi user access cataloging system?

Tags: software, lightroom, lightroom-catalog

I am running a studio of 6 artists and I am looking for a solution to organize images essentially exactly like lightroom does but that can be accessed simultaneously by all of the artists. I know that all of the metadata entry must be done manually and that is not the problem. I basically need a centralized catalog database with multi user simultaneous access.  I have looked into both Extensis DAM and Fotoware DAM

Am awaiting a quote from Extensis and Fotoware has no information listed about simultaneous access from multiple users.

Does anyone know of any other DAM software?

Comment: I would assume that Fotoware supports simultaneous access from multiple users (not in the lowest price category which is for one computer only). Why? Because otherwise the customers would be very unhappy.

Comment: Relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33524/what-product-image-catalog-system-do-companies-with-thousands-of-products-like-t/33540#33540 and: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/4214/9161

Comment: Extensis is the defacto standard for this and realy works. You may want to check Phase One which has a new DAM application. It says that you can share databases which is different than concurrently working on a catalog but it *may* suit your needs depending on how your users cooperate.

Answer (score 4):

Daminion is one option. It costs 1506 € ( http://www.daminion.net/order ) for 6 users.

I have not used it.

Comment: I almost bought this.... found out at checkout that it is only A windows application.

Comment: BTW Daminion can import all your image annotations entered by Lightroom, including hierarchical keywords from Camera RAW images. It can be launched on a Mac via Parallels Desktop or Campboot.

Comment: The latest Daminion Server 4.6 version has a web-client that allows you to access it from Macs, Tablets and Smartphones...

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Experience Manager is another DAM, though I am unsure how expensive it may be.  It integrates with the Adobe Drive client and works with Bridge.  Not sure if it integrates with Lightroom at all though.  I've not personally had opportunity to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Photo Supreme offers a cross platform multi user solution. It uses a either a PostgreSQL or SQL Server database.